# Do we want feeds in the chatroom? If so, which and what should we call them?

Tags: discussion, chat

Most sites set up feeds into their chatroom for questions on their main and meta site.

There are two options: Have a feeds user post these into the room itself, as oneboxed posts (like [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54084198#54084198)), or as a ticker feed that appears in the top of the chat screen (looking like [the image in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257023/369802)).

For oneboxed posts, the feeds users can also get creative names and profile pictures.

So, does this site want these feeds? If so, oneboxes or ticker? And do you have creative names/pictures in case of oneboxing?

Comment: For people worried about noise, it might be worth keeping https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170660/369802 in mind. You can ignore the feed, both ticker feeds and oneboxed ones :)

Answer (score -3):

<sup>Note: this was an answer I gave on Day 1 when this SE first opened and we were getting dozens of questions/hour. For my opinion almost 1 month after we opened, see below.</sup>

---

**Answer at the time the question was asked:**

In the last hour we have had dozens of questions.

Both the one-boxed feeds, and the less annoying "ticker feeds" are a bit too distracting for me personally, and considering the volume of questions right now, I would suggest not to have ticker or one-boxed feeds for now.

---

**Answer about 1 month later:**

I still like the chat room the way it is. We are at 4 questions/day, which means that one-boxed feeds would still be taking over the chat room when compared to actual chat messages. The ticker feeds would be less harmful, because all the user has to do is click "dismiss" if they want to remove the ticker feed. I personally don't need the ticker feed either, but I'm less strongly opinionated about these, and I would be happy with whatever the community decides on this one. In the chat room 3 days ago, this question was revisited and the only response I saw was [this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54302062#54302062) which had the same opinion as me; but maybe to re-visit this "properly" we can have anyone that wants feeds to answer here and see how many upvotes they get.